# Is it possible to pre-select level before loading Forge3D viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

In the attached image, the minimap circled in red can be selected as floor(level).
Is it possible to pre-select it before loading Forge3D viewer?

[minimap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maqku.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways in which you can control *what* exactly gets loaded into the viewer:

- The Forge Model Derivative service can generate multiple outputs (also called "viewables" or "derivatives") for a single design file. For example, in case of Revit designs, the service generates separate viewables for each 3D view and each 2D sheet. So if you have control over the input design files, you could perhaps create a custom 3D view for each floor in the original design, and then instruct the viewer to load the specific viewable with your floor.
- Forge Viewer loads an entire viewable by default but you can also configure it to only load a subset of geometries from a viewable. This is done by passing a list of object IDs to the loader as explained in this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only. Of course, this means that you would have to be able to identify objects belonging to a specific floor. That is a topic for another question, though.

Comment: Thanks.   @Petr Broz   I was working on a demo similar to [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/ja/node/1765) and I am wondering if it is possible select level from 2D model viewer variable. It is poosible get the level from `viewport.findLevelForViewport()` But not find any sample for set the level up from 2d viewer which would work from 3d viewer. So is viewables or derivatives really relevant. If yes which function should I use, if not what would possible work in my case.

Comment: It sounds like what you're asking for is being able to detect the level from a 3D model based on some user input? For example, when the user clicks on an element in the 3D view, you'd like to be able to find out which floor the clicked element belongs to, is that right?

Comment: I don't think we have a method that would do all of this for you but the viewer API does include tools that you could use to find the answer. For example, you can find all the levels in your design using `Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(viewer.model.getDocumentNode())`, and using the viewer API you can find out the bounding box of each design element. Then, you can check if the bounding box of a specific element sits between any two floor elevations?

Comment: Thanks for reply. @Petr Broz  I find out that 2d sheet IS related to level of 3d model, and depend on what I was asked is: 'pre select the level of 3d model from 2d model viewer'. So it seems that I don't really need any method to get the level from.